# Code running on two GPUs does not reach concurrent execution and has irrelevant speedup

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, multi-gpu

I have code like this:

```
for(int i =0; i<2; i++)
{
    //initialization of memory and some variables
    ........
    ........
    RunDll(input image, output image); //function that calls kernel
}
```

Each iteration in the above loop is independent. I want to run them concurrently. So, I tried this:

```
for(int i =0; i<num_devices; i++)
{
    cudaSetDevice(i);
    //initialization of memory and some variables
    ........
    ........
    RunDll(input image, output image); 
    {
        RunBasicFBP_CUDA(parameters); //function that calls kernel 1

        xSegmentMetal(parameters); //CPU function

        RunBasicFP_CUDA(parameters);  //function that uses output of kernel 1 as input for kernel 2

        for (int idx_view = 0; idx_view < param.fbp.num_view; idx_view++)
        {
            for (int idx_bin = 1; idx_bin < param.fbp.num_bin-1; idx_bin++)
            {
                sino_diff[idx_view][idx_bin] = sino_org[idx_view][idx_bin] - sino_mask[idx_view][idx_bin];
            }
        }

        RunBasicFP_CUDA(parameters);
        if(some condition)
        {
            xInterpolateSinoLinear(parameters);  //CPU function
        }
        else
        {
            xInterpolateSinoPoly(parameters);  //CPU function
        }

        RunBasicFBP_CUDA( parameters );
    }
}
```

I am using 2 GTX 680 and I want to use these two devices concurrently. With the above code, I am not getting any speed-up. The processing time is almost the same as that when running on a single GPU.

*How can I reach concurrent execution on the two available devices?*

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more details regarding what `RunDll` actually does. If it contains blocking API calls, then it would be very likely that serialization will occur.

Comment: RunDll has two kernels and they are being launched one by one. Kernels do have `cudaThreadSynchronize()` and `__syncthreads()`. But I am not using `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` anywhere in code. What else do you mean by blocking API?

Comment: @talonmies I edited my question. Hope, it is more clear now.

Comment: Yesterday you posted the question [Concurrently running two for loops with same number of loop cycles involving GPU and CPU tasks on two GPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607430/concurrently-running-two-for-loops-with-same-number-of-loop-cycles-involving-gpu) in which you mentioned non-concurrently running CPU functions and kernels in each `for` loop cycle. Is it the same problem? Furthermore, you were asked to provide some more details on the `RunDll` function, but your edit does not appear to do so.

Comment: `cudaThreadSynchronize()` is equivalent to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` (and the former is actually deprecated - http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/deprecated.html#deprecated)

Comment: So, I cant run these two devices concurrently?

Comment: Of course you can, but not if you synchronise in between launching work on one and the other. You should have asynchronous calls only in `RunDLL` if your want them to run asynchronously. You've updated your question with more detail, but still haven't actually given enough info since there's no information about what you're doing in `RunBasicFP_CUDA`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your are not using `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. If you are using synchronous CPU<->GPU memory transactions (`cudaMemcpy`) they will have a synchronization effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your comment you say:

> RunDll has two kernels and they are being launched one by one. Kernels do have cudaThreadSynchronize()

Note that `cudaThreadSynchronize()` is equivalent to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` (and the former is actually [deprecated](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/deprecated.html#deprecated)) which means that you will run on one GPU, synchronise, then run on the other GPU. Also note that `cudaMemcpy()` is a blocking routine, you would need the `cudaMemcpyAsync()` version to avoid all blocking (as pointed out by @JackOLantern in comments).

In general, you will need to post more details of what is inside `RunDLL()` since without that your questions does not have enough information to give a definitive answer. Ideally follow [these guidelines](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

In my answer to your previous post ([Concurrently running two for loops with same number of loop cycles involving GPU and CPU tasks on two GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607430/concurrently-running-two-for-loops-with-same-number-of-loop-cycles-involving-gpu)), I pointed out that you would not have achieved a speedup of `2` when using `2` GPUs.

To explain why, let us consider the following code snippet

```
Kernel1<<<...,...>>>(...); // assume Kernel1 takes t1 seconds

// assume CPUFunction + cudaMemcpys take tCPU seconds
cudaMemcpy(...,...,...,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); // copy the results of Kernel1 to CPU
CPUFunction(...); // assume it takes tCPU seconds
cudaMemcpy(...,...,...,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // copy data from the CPU to Kernel2

Kernel2<<<...,...>>>(...); // assume it takes t2 seconds
```

It doesn't matter if I'm using `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or `cudaMemcpy` to obtain synchronization.

The cost of executing the above code snippet in the `for` loop on one GPU only is

**t1 + tCPU + t2 + t1 + tCPU + t2 = 2t1 + 2tCPU + 2t2**

In the case of `2` GPUs, if you were able to achieve perfect concurrency of the execution of `Kernel1` and `Kernel2` on the two different GPUs, then the cost of executing the above code snippet would be

**t1 (concurrent execution of `Kernel1` on the two GPUs) + 2*tCPU (you need two calls to the CPU function, each for a different instance of the output of `Kernel1`) + t2 (concurrent execution of `Kernel2` on the two GPUs)**

Accordingly, the speedup achieved by using two GPUs instead of one would be

**(2*(t1 + tCPU + t2))/(t1 + 2tCPU + t2)**

When tCPU is equal to zero, the speedup becomes `2`.

This is an expression of [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law).